# How to handle WebApi error 404

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm implementing MVC 5 application with WebApi2 in a same domain.
My problem now is how to handle error 404 in WebApi. I'm using routing in my WebApi.

```
[RoutePrefix("myapi")]
public class MyApiController : ApiController 
{
[Route("value")]
public string myvalue()
{
return "value";
}
}
```

Now I have my url `"/myapi/value"` that returns value string. The problem is I requested `"/myapi/value/bla/bla"`  or any URL that is not in my API, it returns error 404.

I tried this link http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/handling-http-404-error-in-asp-net-web-api, it only applies in a WebApi project but not in a MVC + WebApi Project.

Please help. TIA

UPDATE:

Please read carefully!!!!

This will be the default page if you don't handle 404 in your WebApi.
It includes here your physical path.

[image]

Comment: Why is the 404 a problem? If the URL is not correct, it should return 404, shouldn't it?

Comment: But the default error page is returned not your custom.

Comment: `/myapi/value/bla/bla` isn't a valid route.

Comment: @Amit, That's what I'm talking about. How to handle those invalid routes.

Comment: see if this helps : http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/exception-handling

Comment: Invalid routes isn't exception.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

I think the following has a better description on how to implement error handling for a WebApi 2+ project: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/error-handling/web-api-global-error-handling .

There are two problems I had in my projects when combining the MVC and WebApi in the same project.

The first being that my error handling of my normal MVC pages did not work anymore. To resolve this I initialized the WebApi routing first, over the MVC controller routing and made some small adjustments in the web.config like described in your post.

Secondly if you want to handle invalid webapi routings, for example the correct directory but with wrong values which can not be resolved. try the solution in the "Global error handling" section of the below link: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/looking-at-asp-net-mvc-5-1-and-web-api-2-1-part-4-web-api-help-pages-bson-and-global-error-handling

Comment: You should flag as duplicate.

Comment: Same applies to combination projects of MVC and WebApi

Comment: Basically I had my WebApi routings which (if not resolved) where taken over by my default routing of MVC that handled the error page.

Comment: Try to use POSTMAN to request to your webapi and request an invalid url. For example you have a url 'api/values' to your web api then try to 'api/values/123/123/123/123'. It makes a difference.

Comment: Invalid routes isn't exception.

Comment: This is what I'm following. http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/handling-http-404-error-in-asp-net-web-api.

Comment: Could you include your global asax?